# How can limit a certain number of decimal places being shown without rounding?

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

I would like to be able to limit the amount of decimal places that are shown from a print function without any sort of rounding system

v = 8.836333333333339

print ('%.2f' % v)

This code will print the value of v to two decimal places but also rounds it up or down, how could I make it stop this rounding please?

Comment: What do you **want** to see for your example?  8.83 would be rounded down, and 8.84 would be rounded up.  What on Earth do you mean by "stop this rounding"?  That is, you don't want to see 8.83 or 8.84, so what **do** you want to see?

Comment: Really sorry. here is what I meant to ask                              v = 8.836333333333339

print ('%.2f' % v)                                                        That prints out 8.84, how would I keep it at 8.83?

Comment: @TimPeters: I think what he is describing is truncation; both 8.843 and 8.848 should become 8.84.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could process it as a string:

```
v = 8.836333333333339
s = str(v)
print s[:s.find('.')+3]

# prints 8.83
```

Comment: Ahhh this has worked like a charm. Thank you very much, if I had enough rep to vote that answer up I would, and I shall once I have enough :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know how long the number will be, you can easily accomplish this with string slicing.

```
>>> v = 8.836333333333339
>>> x = str(v) # get string representation of 'v'
>>> x
'8.836333333333339'

>>> y = x[0:4] # every character in 'x' between 0 and 4 but not including 4
>>> y
'8.83'

>>> v = float(y) # you can even convert it back to a number if you want
>>> v
8.83
```

Comment: This was also useful, I'll be sure to look more into type conversion, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using decimal module :

```
>>> help(Decimal.quantize)
Help on method quantize in module decimal:

quantize(self, exp, rounding=None, context=None, watchexp=True) unbound decimal.Decimal    
method
    Quantize self so its exponent is the same as that of exp.

Similar to self._rescale(exp._exp) but with error checking.


>>> from decimal import *
>>> v = 8.834333333333339
>>> print Decimal(v).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
8.83
>>> print Decimal('8.8663').quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
8.87 
>>> print Decimal('8.863').quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
8.86
>>>
```

Comment: When I run this in my Python shell it still rounds off the last number. Also I don't know if this is because we have different versions of Python but I needed to put an extra set of brackets from the word Decimal to the end the line for all 3 examples.

Answer (score 0):

A bit specific to your case, but you could also use `int` to truncate:

```
 >>> print(int(v*100)/100.0)
 8.83
```

It times at about 3x faster (310 ns vs 925 ns) than the string `find`-based approach.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php
$value_exp = explode(".", 245.788968);
$value_new = floatval($value_exp[0].'.'.substr($value_exp[1],0,4));
echo $value_new; //output will 245.7889
?>
```

Comment: I think author wanted truncation in python